# Node, Link, Node, Link, Node: Linking Nodes into a LinkedList

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

For practice in Python OOP (first time) and for some relaxation from trying to learn Serialization in Java, I decided to write a LinkedList in Python. Now, this class would be pretty useless, because in Python, instead of:

(Java)

```
int[] array = new int[size];
// initialization...
// Now add an object to the end
int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, size + 1);
newArray[size] = value; // Really annoying, is it not?
```

You can do:

```
array = [] # And other values
array.append(value)
```

When you want to add a value. But, since it's for practice, it's not for use.

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first = None
        self.last = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, value):
        '''
        Adds the specified element to the end of the array.
        '''

        if not self.first: # first is None
            self.first = Node(None, None, value)
            self.last = self.first
        else:
            node = Node(self.last, None, value)
            self.last.after = node
            self.last = node

        self.size += 1

    def add_at(self, value, index):
        '''
        Adds the specified element at the specified position.

        If the given index is out of range of the list, the
        element is added to the end.
        '''

        if index >= self.size:
            self.add(value)

        if index == 0:
            new = Node(None, self.first, value)
            self.first.before = new
            self.first = new

        node = self.get_node(index)
        new = Node(node, node.after, value)
        node.after.before = node
        node.after = new

        self.size += 1

    def remove(self, index):
        '''
        Removes the specified element at the specified position.

        If the given index is out of range of the list, an
        IndexError is thrown.
        '''

        node = self.get_node(index)
        node.before.after = node.after
        node.after.before = node.before
        return node.value

    def get(self, index):
        '''
        Returns the specified element at the specified position.

        If the given index is out of range of the list, an
        IndexError is thrown.
        '''

        return self.get_node(index).value

    def get_node(self, index):
        '''
        Returns the specified node at the specified position.

        If the given index is out of range of the list, an
        IndexError is thrown.
        '''
        if index >= self.size:
            raise IndexError()

        node = None
        if index > self.size / 2:
            # From back
            node = self.last
            for i in range(index, self.size - 1):
                node = node.before
        else:
            # From front
            node = self.first
            for i in range(1, index):
                node = node.after

        return node

class Node:

    def __init__(self, before, after, value):
        self.before = before
        self.after = after
        self.value = value
```

Concerns:

1. I think I can separate Python from Java anc C++ now, so the `;` is no longer there. But just in case, is there a stray `;`?
2. Is the way this class is constructed Pythonic?
3. Are the docstrings good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Methods & Naming

You're building a collection so, implicitly, you're building a contract with your user that your class will act like a collection, that you'll stick to a protocol for collections objects.

If you wan't to grasp a little more on what I’m trying to say, you can read [this article](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/).

So, even though I agree with [@Dair](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/114820/84718) that `size` would be “saffer” as `_size` (but hey, [we’re all responsible adults around here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064400/5069029)), I strongly disagree with the `size` property. You should implement it as a `__len__` method and use it like:

```
stuff = LinkedList()
length = len(stuff)
```

Some other methods can have more common names too:

- `add` \$->\$ `apppend`;
- `add_at` \$->\$ `insert` or `__setitem__`:

  `__setitem__` will allow you to do `stuff[3] = 'some value'` and then `insert` is just a call to `self[index] = value`.

  You will need to change the signature to `def __setitem__(self, key, value)`.
- `remove` \$->\$ `pop` (or maybe `__delitem__`); `remove` is prefered to remove by value instead of by index.
- `get` \$->\$ `__getitem__`: it will allow you to do `the_value = stuff[3]`; you should also remove `get_node` as there is little to no interest in exposing your internals to the user.

## Methods that are missing

You could implement an `__iter__` method that will allow you to do:

```
stuff = LinkedList()
# populate stuff
for elem in stuff: # will use __iter__, or fail back to __len__ + __getitem__ if not available
    do_something(elem)
```

It will also help you shorten `__getitem__`. You can use something along the lines of:

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.first
    while node is not None: # No self.size involved, yay
        yield node.value
        node = node.after
```

You can also implement the `__reversed__` iterator using the same logic (and use it in `__getitem__` too.

Using a parameter to `__init__` that default to `None` would also be usefull to build a `LinkedList` out of any iterable:

```
def __init__(self, other=None):
    self._size = 0
    self.first = None
    self.last = None

    if other is not None:
        for element in other:
            self.append(element)
```

It is then easy to create `stuff = LinkedList([1,2,8,12])`.

And finally, you should consider adding a `__str__` or `__repr__` method so you can `print(stuff)`. Use `__iter__` to simplify it.

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know about all the built-in names. Is there  some documentation with a complete list?

Comment: For "magic methods" names, have a look at [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names). For the other ones such as `insert` or `append`, `help([])` in an interactive session might come in handy.